# Degrees of freedom in OLS regresison vs Bootstrap

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, bootstrap, degrees-of-freedom

I understand that in OLS, the degrees of freedom for estimating the variance of the residuals is *n-q-1*. We loose *q+1* degrees because they are "used" to analytically determine the *q* parameters and *1* intercept and thereby impose restrictions on the linear system.

However, would you still loose these degrees of freedom if you estimated the model via bootstrapping?
Since the coefficients are not analytically determined any more but rather iteratively "guessed", would you still lose the *q+1* degrees of freedom? By guessing the coefficient values, one does not place any restrictions any more.

For example if I define the following loglikelihood function which is minimized with respect to rho:

```
function loglike(rho, y, x)
    u = y - x*rho[1:(end)]
    variance = var(u)

    dist = Normal(0, sqrt(variance))
    contributions = logpdf(dist,u)
    loglikeValue = sum(contributions) 
    return (-loglikeValue)
end
```

What would be the degrees of freedom for determining the variance of the residuals **during each** iteration?
With OLS it would be:

```
variance = sum((u-mean(u))^2)/(n-q-1)
```

While bootstrapping, am I correct to use the following?

```
variance = var(u)
```

Comment: Exactly what do you propose to do with these degrees of freedom, however they might be defined?  In most bootstrapping situations they wouldn't be relevant.  There might be some confusion between *functional* degrees of freedom (as you describe them here) and the "degrees of freedom" that determine appropriate $t$ and $F$ distributions of OLS statistics (which has nothing to do with bootstrapping).  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921 for the distinction.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I want to know if I must use 
variance = sum((u-mean(u))^2)/(n-q-1)
for computing the variance of the residuals while bootstrapping or whether I need to use
variance = sum((u-mean(u))^2)/(n-1) = var(u)

Comment: I'm not following what "estimated the model" is intended to mean: are you trying to fit the coefficients or are you focused on estimating the error variance?